Collision detection issue with entity speed in 2D Top-Down RPG Game
I’m working on a 2D Top-Down RPG and facing an issue with my collision detection. I have two classes: Entity.java and CollisionManager.java.
The Entity class contains attributes like speed and a BoundingBox (represented by a Rectangle object). Before moving the entity, I call a method from the CollisionManager class to check for collisions with the tiles.
The problem is that when I increase the entity’s speed, the collision is detected too early, a few pixels before the entity actually reaches the tile.
CollisionManager.java (checkTile method):
    public void checkTile(Entity entity) {
        int entityLeftWorldX = entity.worldX + entity.boundingBox.x;
        int entityRightWorldX = entityLeftWorldX + entity.boundingBox.width; // Cambiato per maggiore chiarezza
        int entityTopWorldY = entity.worldY + entity.boundingBox.y;
        int entityBottomWorldY = entityTopWorldY + entity.boundingBox.height; // Cambiato per maggiore chiarezza


        int entityLeftColumn = entityLeftWorldX / wm.TILE_SIZE;
        int entityRightColumn = entityRightWorldX / wm.TILE_SIZE;
        int entityTopRow = entityTopWorldY / wm.TILE_SIZE;
        int entityBottomRow = entityBottomWorldY / wm.TILE_SIZE;

        switch (entity.currentDirection) {
            case UP -> entityTopRow = (entityTopWorldY - entity.speed) / wm.TILE_SIZE;
            case DOWN -> entityBottomRow = (entityBottomWorldY + entity.speed) / wm.TILE_SIZE;
            case LEFT -> entityLeftColumn = (entityLeftWorldX - entity.speed) / wm.TILE_SIZE;
            case RIGHT -> entityRightColumn = (entityRightWorldX + entity.speed) / wm.TILE_SIZE;
        }

        int[] topTiles = {
                wm.firstLayerMap.GAME_MAP[entityLeftColumn][entityTopRow],
                wm.firstLayerMap.GAME_MAP[entityRightColumn][entityTopRow]
        };

        int[] bottomTiles = {
                wm.firstLayerMap.GAME_MAP[entityLeftColumn][entityBottomRow],
                wm.firstLayerMap.GAME_MAP[entityRightColumn][entityBottomRow]
        };

        if (isTileColliding(topTiles) || isTileColliding(bottomTiles)) {
            entity.isColliding = true;
        }
    }

    private boolean isTileColliding(int... tileNums) {
        for (int tileNum : tileNums) {
            if (tileNum >= 0 && isTileSolid(tileNum, wm.firstLayerMap)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isTileSolid(int tileNum, TileManager layer) {
        return layer != null && layer.tileMap.get(tileNum) != null && layer.tileMap.get(tileNum).isSolid;
    }

Call to the method in Entity.java:
private void updatePosition() {
        if(currentState == State.WALKING) {
            isColliding = false;

            cm.checkTile(this);

            if(!isColliding) {
                switch(currentDirection) {
                    case UP -> worldY -= speed;
                    case DOWN -> worldY += speed;
                    case LEFT -> worldX -= speed;
                    case RIGHT -> worldX += speed;
                }
            }
        }
    }


Hi there, please add your code in the body of your question, not through a link. Please check the How To Ask section.

Hello, sorry about that. Thanks :) I added it.

You are checking the if (isTileColliding(topTiles) || isTileColliding(bottomTiles)) after you already moved the positions in your Entity, you should do that before moving?

Hello Luca, I think the problem is that you are using velocities greater than 1 px, so, if you have velocity = 5, and before moving you check if there is collision, you will not move and you will stay 5 px from the object, instead, if you check after moving, you will be superimposed to the object, therefore, use velocities equal or less than 1.

The java.awt.Rectangle class has an intersects method.

The problem is that the character doesn't move if the collision is detected; instead, its position should be adjusted just enough to not make it clip into the tiles.
